# How can I list files containing conflict markers without duplicates?

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm using `git diff --name-only -S====` to try to list files with conflict markers, because sometimes I've resolved a conflict in my text editor but I forgot to mark it as merged. But the problem is, if files have multiple conflicts, the file is listed multiple times, one for each conflict. Is there a way to do this without duplicates?

I would prefer a solution using `git` only and not using UNIX tools, so that it can be run regardless of whether in Windows command prompt or a Bash shell. However, if it's not possible using `git` only then a solution with UNIX tools will be okay.

Also, if there's a better way to detect conflict markers that would be great, because the string `====` may appear for other reasons, although for the particular codebase I'm working on this is very rare.

Comment: `git diff --name-only -S==== | sort -u` seems to be the obvious UNIX-world solution (and it works also in the Git for Windows bash terminal), but I'll let people answer if they have a pure git solution?

Comment: If you are searching for files _on your disk_ which contain conflict markers, wouldn't `grep` work ?  `grep -e ===== -l -r .`

Comment: But to be fair, the overarching problem is "*because **sometimes** I've resolved a conflict in my text editor but I forgot to mark it as merged*" ...how often do you do that? I suspect the uncautious use of `git add .` or `git commit -a` ...I'd suggest `git add -p` to better keep track of what's actually commited.

Comment: @RomainValeri It happens all the time. I never use `git add .` or `git add -a` when merging. That's not the problem, the problem is an action I took completely outside of git and then forgot to update git to match.

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```bash
git ls-files --unmerged
```

to get a list of all files that git consider to be in conflict and has not yet been marked as resolved with `git add`.

This will give 2 or 3 lines per file regardless of number of conflicts inside the file. To filter down to unique lines you can run

```bash
git ls-files --unmerged | cut -d "      " -f2- | uniq
# A single tab character between the double quotes
```

Notice that this is slightly different than searching for the conflict markers (that might accidentally be added and committed), so probably you can combine both approaches to a `find-conflicted-files.sh` script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# A single tab character between the double quotes
(
        git ls-files --unmerged | cut -d "      " -f2-
        git diff --name-only -S====
) | sort -u
```

---

However having said all that, I would rather recommend [using KDiff3 to resolve conflicts](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3), because with that it is not possible to resolve a conflict and forget to mark it as merged. When a conflict is resolved it is done.

And besides a proper, full 3-way merge operation is **superior** to just a 2-way conflict view that the was majority of IDEs/editors provide.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! `git ls-files --unmerged` doesn't help me unfortunately, as I'm only interested in those files which are unmerged AND still have merge conflict markers. As I mentioned in my original post, this is because I sometimes resolve a conflict in the text editor but forget to mark it as merged. If I just want to see a list of all files not marked as merged, `git status` can give me that.